# Struggling converting java RxBle Code to Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, reactivex, rxandroidble

Im currently developing an android app with Kotlin. Its my first experience with this programming language and im currently struggeling to translate an example of Java code to Kotlin.

I want to implement the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39140906/how-to-concatenate-two-observable-operations-in-a-linear-fashion-do-first-this) question in Kotlin.

my current implementation fails to compile because the Ovservable::from method seems to be removed.

This is my current approach:

```java
connectionObservable!!.flatMap { connection ->
                    connection.discoverServices()
                            .flatMap { services ->
                                services.getService(UUID.fromString("My UUID")).map(BluetoothGattService::getCharacteristics)
                                          //here occurs the error, he wants a Single Source but got a observable with the ble characteristic
                                          .flatMap { characteristics: MutableList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> -> Observable.fromIterable(characteristics) }
                                        .flatMap { characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic ->
                                            connection.setupNotification(characteristic)
                                                    .flatMap { observable: Observable<ByteArray> -> observable ,Pair<BluetoothGattCharacteristic, ByteArray>(characteristic, observable)}

                                        }
                            }
                }.subscribe { pair: Pair<BluetoothGattCharacteristic, ByteArray> ->
                    genericModel[pair.first.uuid] = pair.second
                    throwable -> { /* handle errors */ }
                }
```

Can you point out my errors so i can understand what im doing wrong?

Thanks in advance! 
Jonas

Comment: flatmap {Observable.from(getCharacteristics) is not enough?

Comment: i updated the code tro clearify. He wants a SingleSource but got a Observable after this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several potential issues with your code.

1. First of all the code is not syntactically correct — see this line:

```
.flatMap { observable: Observable<ByteArray> -> observable ,Pair<BluetoothGattCharacteristic, ByteArray>(characteristic, observable)}
```

I assume you probably wanted to `flatMap` the `observable: Observable<ByteArray>` (type added by me for clarity) to get from it `ByteArray` objects. This would look like this:

```
.flatMap { observable: Observable<ByteArray> -> observable.map { bytes -> Pair(characteristic, bytes) }}
```

2. Additionally the code will not compile as you try to return an `Observable` from a lambda which expects a `SingleSource` — exactly as your compiler says. If you have a `Single` and you will `.flatMap` it — it's lambda is supposed to return another `SingleSource`. There is a `.flatMapObservable` function that expects `ObservableSource` which is what you should use. The end result would look like:

```
    connectionObservable!!.flatMap { connection ->
        connection.discoverServices()
            .flatMapObservable { services ->
                services.getService(UUID.fromString("My UUID")).map(BluetoothGattService::getCharacteristics)
                    //here occurs the error, he wants a Single Source but got a observable with the ble characteristic
                    .flatMapObservable { characteristics: MutableList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> -> Observable.fromIterable(characteristics) }
                    .flatMap { characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic ->
                        connection.setupNotification(characteristic)
                            .flatMap { observable: Observable<ByteArray> -> observable.map { bytes -> Pair(characteristic, bytes) }}

                    }
            }
    }.subscribe { pair: Pair<BluetoothGattCharacteristic, ByteArray> ->
        genericModel[pair.first.uuid] = pair.second
        throwable -> { /* handle errors */ }
    }
```

3. `Observable.fromIterable()` is still the API of `Observable`. You probably do not use the `Observable` class from proper package. There is an `Observable` class in package `java.util` but we are using here one from `RxJava 2` which has package `io.reactivex`